# Typescript if string is included in options

Tags: typescript

When I make an if statement like this typescript knows it is either `"a"` or `"b"`

```
if (str === "a" || str === "b") {
    // typescript knows it is either "a" or "b"
}
```

But that is too verbose, and with many options it can look even worse.

**Is there a shorter way of doing that, with typescript being able to infer the same thing as above?** I am thinking somehting like this

```
if (["a", "b"].includes(str)) {
    // too bad typescript doesn't know that it is either "a" or "b" only
}
```

I oversimplified the example, but a more complete example can be seen here, where I need to know if an arbitrary string is the name of a boolean property in an interface:

```
interface Filters {
    isPromo?: boolean,
    isFreeShipping?: boolean,
    isNew?: boolean,
    isInStock?: boolean,
    title?: string
}

let filters: Filters = {};

for (const filterValuePair of location.search.split("&")) {
    const [urlFilter, value] = filterValuePair.split("=");
    // here typescript has no warnings because it can tell that it must be a boolean property because of how the "if" is implemented
    if (urlFilter === "isPromo" || urlFilter === "isFreeShipping" || urlFilter === "isNew" || urlFilter === "isInStock") {
        filters[urlFilter] = Boolean(value);
    }
    // this is more succint, but typescript cannot help me infer
    if (["isPromo", "isFreeShipping", "isNew", "isInStock"].includes(urlFilter)) {
        filters[urlFilter] = Boolean(value);
    }
}
```

See [playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQ4SwOwFwUwJwGYEMDGNgDEwBtZwM7ADeAUKOePgApwD2AtrQPwBcwARrbdjEhADRkKIMPgxwYMAMoALMAAd5kAOasOXHn0HCR+AHIwA7ms7deAocNEBJCFKi0UAaxMbz2nVDBQea-FDgVS2AAXxJgnihgBBw8fDYsXHhCAF5iEIBucPIEWjhgAAoUWgh-aNj4ADUkbABXGCokMHzaBGBsRyQvEoA6fF44FBk++WxvAoAiADIJgEpZ4mDyYtKogG1auGxEvH5gADca+oBdYDSYpLhquoamuBGxqEmUuaydYAB6D+AZeHQoACe8hg+BQgXkURkSEIEFowEMSDgEBUhHYMBQSFq-XAUQxEGAsGw2AJUKi3mA9CxUTRwCQ6jMfGA8jowLggI46Mx2NaP1ohhJ6AmYAQE0o4Hooxg9Bg0BgABMlqBhYVNtsKvkUprgELqHRGKKAD4G4CqnbwM5anXiSSyBRKCDKQ3G03qi1pHUGQxOk1bM0ay02OwOZxzRbvHLq-AbX3q05pABCbj4BUON1mbx0YXeXxJojFjAkwHwtRQKEgUD27FqUUBwNB4NxfFhkJg2HkFPQkAQ8EVIjaBTWOpoDFoEz2Vok0jkihUY+1ok9c51tnsjicE2OPUgKDqcpBBRdl3mYfDIAucWjasuceAiYZEBTRxg6d7oWCYSAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) which is a function where you assert *"if this function returns true, then some variable is some type."*

We can use `includes` as the implementation of the function and assert your type through the return.

```
const isFilterKey = <K extends string & keyof Filters>(
    properties: K[], urlFilter: string
): urlFilter is K => {
    return (properties as string[]).includes(urlFilter);
}
```

We have to say `(properties as string[]).includes(urlFilter)` instead of just `properties.includes(urlFilter)` because `properties` is of type `K[]`, so it expects `includes` to be called with a variable of type `K`.  (Alternatively, you could do `properties.includes(urlFilter as K)`, but I find the other version more semantically sound since we know that `properties` is a subset of `string[]` but we don't know that `urlFilter` is `K`).

```
if (isFilterKey(["isPromo", "isFreeShipping", "isNew", "isInStock"], urlFilter)) {
    filters[urlFilter] = Boolean(value);
}
```

In this example, it's fine to assign `filters[urlFilter]` since the type of `urlFilter` is now known to be the union of the keys in that array.

[Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/nWPGYm)

In a more general sense, like your `"a" | "b"` example, your typeguard would look like:

```
const isSpecificString = <K extends string>(
    strings: K[], value: string
): value is K => {
    return (strings as string[]).includes(value);
}
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you very much :) I continue to be impressed about how Typescript has tackled the many challenges of typing a loosely typed language :D